# LINQ select return type

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, class

in my domain service class i want to return part of my object but returns nothing.

Silverlight code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     LoadOperation<Employees> loadOpKKM = this._employeeContext.Load(this._employeeContext.GetEmployeesById2Query(1));
     loadOpKKM.Completed += new EventHandler(loadOpKKM_Completed);
}

void loadOpKKM_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show(loadOpKKM.Entities.Count().ToString());
}
```

Domain service class:

```
public IQueryable<Employees> GetEmployeesById2(int employeeId)
{    
    var query = from s in ObjectContext.Employees
                 where (s.EmployeeID == employeeId)
                 select new Employees()
                 {
                    Address = s.Address
                 };

    return query;
}
```

where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the entityname plural or is that a Typo in `IQueryable<Employees>` because `IQueryable` already implies that you can have zero or more of `Employee`, which is afcourse the Singularized name. Also, have you put a breakpoint on `return query` and checked `ObjectContext.Employees` and `query` if they contain anything and afcourse at least if the Database contains the specified ID.

Comment: Here is not clear what is a problem

Comment: for example i want to take only address data not all of data from database how can i do it.

Comment: Don't you get an exception like "The entity or complex type 'Employees' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query"? But why not return the Address only? (Not wrapped in an otherwise useless Employee).

Comment: @GertArnold  no i dont get any exception.for example i want to take only address and city data. like "select address,city from employeeTable where employeeId=2"

Answer (score 0):

As Silverming, GertArnold said you should first check if your table is correctly set.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     LoadOperation<Employees> loadOpKKM = this._employeeContext.Load(this._employeeContext.GetEmployeeByIDQuery(1));
     loadOpKKM.Completed += new EventHandler(loadOpKKM_Completed);
}

void loadOpKKM_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show(loadOpKKM.Entities.Count().ToString());
}


[Query(IsComposable=false)]
public Employees GetEmployeeByID(int employeeID)
{
    return this.ObjectContext.Employees.Single(c => c.EmployeeID == employeeID);
}
```

Review your domain service to see if you didn't do any errors or typo

Answer (score 0):

You should not be able to access `loadOpKKM` inside `loadOpKKM_Completed` as shown. It is outside the scope of that method (and should not compile unless you have another property of the same name).

I am guessing you are actually accessing another property called `loadOpKKM` on your page (which will be empty as it is not the temporary one loaded). Check your designer file for that page and see if you also have a property/control called `loadOpKKM`.

*If not please list all the code for the page (including designer file).*

Answer (score 0):

as @Hitech Magic said, loadOpKKM is outside the scope of that method.

try use it like this :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     LoadOperation<Employees> loadOpKKM = this._employeeContext.Load(this._employeeContext.GetEmployeeByIDQuery(1));
     loadOpKKM.Completed += new EventHandler(loadOpKKM_Completed);
}

void loadOpKKM_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     LoadOperation<Employees> loadOpKKM = (LoadOperation<Employees>)sender;
     if(loadOpKKM != null)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(loadOpKKM.Entities.Count().ToString());
     }
     else
     {
         //TODO
     }
}
```